# Error assigning label ID to span: not in StringStore

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

since i'm very new to spacy & python,here i'm trying to create a user defined label to recognize phrase matching, while parsing i'm unable to assign hash value to the 'label', encountring "Error while assigning label Id XXXX to a span object"

```
enter code here
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
from spacy.tokens import Span

class EntityMatcher(object):
    name = 'entity_matcher'

    def __init__(self, nlp, terms, label):
        patterns = [nlp(text) for text in terms]
        self.matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
        self.matcher.add(label, None, *patterns)

    def __call__(self, doc):
        matches = self.matcher(doc)
        for match_id, start, end in matches:
            span = Span(doc, start, end, label=match_id)
            doc.ents = list(doc.ents) + [span]
        return doc

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
terms = (u'cat', u'dog', u'tree kangaroo', u'giant sea spider')
entity_matcher = EntityMatcher(nlp, terms, 'ANIMAL')

nlp.add_pipe(entity_matcher, after='ner')
print(nlp.pipe_names)  # the components in the pipeline

doc = nlp(u"This is a text about Barack Obama and a tree kangaroo")
print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])

****[Error]****
File "new.py", line 17, in __call__
span = Span(doc, start, end, label=match_id)
File "span.pyx", line 62, in spacy.tokens.span.Span.__cinit__
ValueError: [E084] Error assigning label ID 893087899 to span: not in 
StringStore.
```

Comment: You should provide the complete error message, including the line where the error happened.

Comment: i have modified the problem statement please do verify!!

Comment: This is strange and I can't seem to reproduce the error! Is the code above the error the exact code that's in `new.py`? Or did you change anything? (I'm mostly confused by the `893087899` and where it's coming from. Even if there was a problem and `'ANIMAL'` wasn't in the vocab, the hash value would be `6303828839600189595`.)

Comment: The above code is from new.py . I too am not able to get, why is that (893087899) hash value is being selected and the start(start index) and end(end index) values for the selected pattern is 9 and 11 which is not the index value of the actual pattern in the doc

Comment: why are you assigning match_id to the label in `span = Span(doc, start, end, label=match_id)`

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the label to the nlp vocabulary.

```
from spacy.strings import StringStore

animal_hash = StringStore([u'ANIMAL']) # <-- match id
nlp.vocab.strings.add('ANIMAL')
```

Comment: this worked for me. however not sure why 1) that text isn't already in `nlp.vocab` or 2) why the label needs to be part of the vocab

Answer (score 0):

I got segmentation fault when I use `after='ner'`. I removed the parameter like this,

```
nlp.add_pipe(entity_matcher)
```

No other changes from your code, and got the output as,

```
[('Barack Obama', 'PERSON'), ('tree kangaroo', 'ANIMAL')]
```

I couldn't reproduce your error. Spacy version is '2.0.2'

Comment: i edited the code as you mentioned but still i'm facing the same problem. Spacy version is '2.0.11'

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same error when using the small model `en_core_web_sm` with Spacy '2.0.16'. However, just switching to the bigger model `en_core_web_md` solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution to get the hash:

```
nlp.vocab.strings['ANIMAL']
```